# How to make characters line up in front of a kiosk at Unity?

Tags: c#, queue, priority-queue

In my project I have a queue struct which contains character models. I need to make them line up. When the first model on the line leaves it, the one behind it must take his place and all the line also should align again. Any idea for the algorithm? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for very general questions, ask on gamedev.com.  this site is only for specific problems with source code.

Comment: FYI "unityscript" is no longer available in Unity, you have to use c#